# gdal.Open fails after h5py.File() but only on Linux

Tags: python, gdal, h5py

I use Python and I open a hdf5 file using h5py to get some info that is not viewed by gdal.
Then, I open the same file using gdal.Open(). On windows, everything works. But when deployed on Linux (Ubuntu) it fails. Gdal compains that

```
RuntimeError: `nyfile.he5' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

Why?

p.s. Now I'm working on a workaround, but it involves copying a structured array and numpy.copy seems to loose the "header" info specific to h5py.

Comment: After some digging I discovered that (on linux only) if the file is opened in gdal, re-opening it in h5py will also not work. It throws access denied. Maybe gdal opens it in exclusive mode by default under linux?.

Comment: Have you checked that your GDAL installation on Ubuntu supports HDF5? You can list all supported formats with `gdalinfo --formats`

Comment: Yep. It's there :
HDF5 (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
HDF5Image (ro): HDF5 Dataset

Comment: In the mean time, the workaround is: Open the file with h5py, get a copy of whatever data I need (luckily is not much) and close the file. Then, move on and read the rasters using gdal. Refactoring everything to h5py would take longer.